# codeigniter hmvc routing is not work on modules Controller but find in CI default Controller on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please any one help me, my codeigniter hmvc routing is not work on modules Controller show error "404 Page not found" but find in CI default Controller on live server. but all are working local server...

Comment: Double check you have named the controller  and file names correct only the first letter upper case. Also check if route work with index.php like `http://www.example.com/index.php/module/controller/function`

Comment: are you set routing rules in routes.php file?

Comment: Thank you So much , Now its working.................

Comment: what is an issue ?route rules settings or others?

Comment: No, modules file naming..Thank you